# Disable telementry VisualStudio Code corporate

Tags: visual-studio-code, telemetry

In VisualStudio Code I'm able to overwrite `"telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false`, but this has to be done manually for each new user. Is there any way to set this through a GPO or Registry setting, so I don't have to run to each user and disable it?

Comment: Ivan, we have the same issue. I have entered a user voice - please vote! https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16656457-allow-gpo-control-of-all-vs-outbound-communication

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are only two scopes for the settings.

**User** these applies only for the user,
**Workspace** these applies only for the project workspace

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but what I want to achive is to push some of the user settings, like the telemetry, through a GPO corporate-wide